# How can I ask a different question depending on the user's answer?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I've found out that it's faster to get a reply here than in Twilio's support, so here it goes: I need to ask the user 3 questions, however, if the first answer is yes, there will be an extra question right on the spot.

Is it possible to do it on the same Collect?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't do that within the same collect as there is no inherent logic in the flow through the JSON.

In my experience, if I needed a conversation to branch at some point that would be the end of one collect and I would start a new one based on the response. You can still remember all of the details throughout the conversation using the [remember function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/remember).

Answer (score 0):

Please provide snippets but I shall attempt to answer the question to the best of my ability. 
If you are referring to the programmable chat function, I would also need to see the language you are using, although:

Create a variable, after asking the question, assign the variable to read the input, here's a basic example in VB.NET:

```
Dim ans As String
Console.WriteLine("Question")
ans = Console.ReadLine()
if (ans = "y")
{
Console.WriteLine("Different Question depending on the scenario")

}

if (ans = "n")
{
Console.WriteLine("Next Question")
Recursion()
/* Recursion the question that both y/n will both have*\
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear, I was referring to the Autopilot's Collect function. 
The language my webhook's are on is Python. 
Thank you for answering!